# What is meant by longitudinal vision position In the phenomenon of apparent shift of an object due to refraction?

Tags: optics, refraction, geometric-optics

[image]

I was studying the topic " **Apparent shift of an object due to refraction** " and found a note in my study package - **whenever the observer is not in the longitudinal vision position then the image of the object has both longitudinal and lateral shift**.

Can anyone please help by explaining the meaning of this statement and giving the appropriate mathematics to solve such questions by giving an example..

Any help will be appreciated.